# How to keep the most recent object in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, mapreduce

I am working with some data in a node back end and have the below data structure returned and I would like to filter it based on tag_id and return the most recent object in the array based on time.

```
{
    "undefined": [
        {
            "tag_id": 1,
            "alias": "Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:57.151Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 1,
            "alias": "Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 1,
            "alias": "Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:23:57.279Z",
            "floor": "Nav Bridge Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 2,
            "alias": "2Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:57.151Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 2,
            "alias": "2Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
    ],
    "b_deck_ccr": [
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:56.551Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_ccr"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:14:12.844Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "zones": [
                "B Deck CCR",
                "B Deck Fire Station"
            ],
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_ccr"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:23:56.199Z",
            "floor": "Nav Bridge Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_ccr"
        }
    ],
    "b_deck_fire_station": [
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:56.551Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_fire_station"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:14:12.844Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_fire_station"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:23:56.199Z",
            "floor": "Nav Bridge Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_fire_station"
        }
    ]
}
```

The data structure above, I would like to reduce to look like the below data structure

```
{
    "undefined": [
        {
            "tag_id": 1,
            "alias": "Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 2,
            "alias": "2Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
    ],
    "b_deck_ccr": [
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:14:12.844Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_ccr"
        }
    ],
    "b_deck_fire_station": [
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:14:12.844Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_fire_station"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried all sorts of grouping and merges but cannot seem to come up with the right combinations of bashing keys as yet!

My thought process for this is:

1. get each array in the object
2. find and group objects in the array by tag_id
3. loop through the grouped objects and return object with the latest timestamp

Am I on the right track or can anyone suggest an alternative?

regards,

Comment: For the first object in your result "undefined",  it has the timestamp of `"time": "2021-06-26T10:25:57.151Z"`, why is that object used and not the object with the `time` of `"time": "2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z"` (which is the latest timestamp)

Comment: Your object is invalid: Formatting issue:             `""in_zone": true,`

Answer (score 1):

As a variant. You can loop over the elements of each group and collect statistics about the last item within id with its index. Then you can replace all group elements with just the last ones by their collected indexes.

```js
const data = {
    "undefined": [
        {
            "tag_id": 1,
            "alias": "Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:57.151Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 1,
            "alias": "Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 1,
            "alias": "Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:23:57.279Z",
            "floor": "Nav Bridge Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 2,
            "alias": "2Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:57.151Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 2,
            "alias": "2Yong",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "in_zone": true,
            "in_correct_zone": false
        },
    ],
    "b_deck_ccr": [
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:56.551Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_ccr"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:14:12.844Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "zones": [
                "B Deck CCR",
                "B Deck Fire Station"
            ],
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_ccr"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:23:56.199Z",
            "floor": "Nav Bridge Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_ccr"
        }
    ],
    "b_deck_fire_station": [
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:25:56.551Z",
            "floor": "A-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_fire_station"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T11:14:12.844Z",
            "floor": "B-Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_fire_station"
        },
        {
            "tag_id": 10,
            "alias": "Lay 1",
            "time": "2021-06-26T10:23:56.199Z",
            "floor": "Nav Bridge Deck",
            "zone_name_alias": "b_deck_fire_station"
        }
    ]
};

for (const group of Object.values(data)) {
  const stat = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    const item = group[i];

    if (stat[item.tag_id] === undefined || stat[item.tag_id].time < item.time) {
      stat[item.tag_id] = { time: item.time, index: i };
    }
  }

  const lasts = Object.values(stat).reduce(
    (acc, item) => {
      acc.push(group[item.index]);
      return acc;
    },
    []
  );

  group.length = 0;
  group.push(...lasts);
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Your times are not same as requested. You are compering strings.

Comment: Yes, but they are the last ones. Let's see whether the author will correct the code or the description.

Comment: And with this format, comparing strings may suffices.

Comment: Yeah im trying to solve this but got stuck on those dates and convert/comparing. So you are saying out of 
`"2021-06-26T10:25:57.151Z"`
`"2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z"`
`"2021-06-26T10:23:57.279Z"`  the `2021-06-26T11:15:58.008Z` is most recent one?

Comment: What format  exactly is that anyway, cant find it anywhere?

Comment: It seems the [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) format.